# Wifi connecting-disabled-connecting loop

Tags: wi-fi

My wifi was perfectly working a few days back, but now all of a sudden all I get is connecting-disconnecting-scanning loop. It never connects. Help.

I'm on Android 2.3.5 | Wildfire S | Rooted
Here's my log:

```
05-02 17:18:50.583: D/StatusBarPolicy(190): onSignalStrengthsChanged
05-02 17:18:50.583: D/StatusBarService(190): updateIcon slot=phone_signal index=20 viewIndex=13 old=StatusBarIcon(pkg=com.android.systemui id=0x7f0200d2 level=0 visible=true num=0 ) icon=StatusBarIcon(pkg=com.android.systemui id=0x7f0200d2 level=0 visible=true num=0 )
05-02 17:18:53.165: D/WifiStateTracker(118): Reset connections and stopping DHCP
05-02 17:18:53.165: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): Rx Data Filter Remove [5] command
05-02 17:18:53.165: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): auto ip enabled
05-02 17:18:53.175: D/NetUtils(118): ifc_get_info addr=0 !
05-02 17:18:54.176: D/WifiStateTracker(118): Disabling interface
05-02 17:18:54.186: W/wpa_supplicant(1323): l2_packet_receive - recvfrom
05-02 17:18:54.216: D/DrmScannerReceiver(398): android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
05-02 17:18:54.246: D/DrmIntentService(398): TIME_THREAD
05-02 17:18:54.246: D/DrmIntentService(398): Wifi disconnected.
05-02 17:18:54.256: D/WifiSettings(352): isDisconnected=true, detailstate=DISCONNECTED, networkId=-1, wifiinfo=SSID: <none>, BSSID: <none>, MAC: 64:A7:69:93:4B:B9, Supplicant state: DISCONNECTED, RSSI: -200, Link speed: 72, Net ID: -1
05-02 17:18:54.276: D/NetSharing_NSReceiver(352): onReceive : android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
05-02 17:18:54.276: I/NetSharing_NSReceiver(352): wifienabled:false
05-02 17:18:58.861: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): Authentication with 00:00:00:00:00:00 timed out.
05-02 17:18:58.861: V/WifiMonitor(118): Event [Authentication with 00:00:00:00:00:00 timed out.]
05-02 17:18:58.861: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=0 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00
05-02 17:18:58.861: V/WifiMonitor(118): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=0 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00]
05-02 17:18:58.871: V/WifiStateTracker(118): Changing supplicant state: DISCONNECTED ==> DISCONNECTED
05-02 17:18:58.971: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=2 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00
05-02 17:18:58.971: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): wpa_driver_wext_combo_scan: Start
05-02 17:18:58.971: V/WifiMonitor(118): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=2 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00]
05-02 17:18:58.971: V/WifiStateTracker(118): Changing supplicant state: DISCONNECTED ==> SCANNING
05-02 17:18:58.971: D/ConnectivityService(118): Dropping ConnectivityChange for WIFI: DISCONNECTED/SCANNING
05-02 17:18:59.542: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): got scan complete
05-02 17:18:59.542: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): wpa_supplicant_get_scan_results:return scan results2
05-02 17:18:59.542: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): AP:ssid[MoDroid],rssi[-30],BSSID=00:26:82:73:2d:d3
05-02 17:18:59.542: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): Received 201 bytes of scan results (1 BSSes)
05-02 17:18:59.542: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): wpa_driver_wext_get_scan_results---
05-02 17:18:59.542: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): wpa_disabled_ssid_list_clear
05-02 17:18:59.542: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): clear disable: MoDroid
05-02 17:18:59.542: W/wpa_supplicant(1323): [EAP-MSG] EAP wpa_supplicant_check_sim@436: eap_methods not available
05-02 17:18:59.542: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): Trying to associate with 00:26:82:73:2d:d3 (SSID='MoDroid' freq=2412 MHz)
05-02 17:18:59.542: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=3 BSSID=00:26:82:73:2d:d3
05-02 17:18:59.562: V/WifiMonitor(118): Event [wpa_disabled_ssid_list_clear]
05-02 17:18:59.562: V/WifiMonitor(118): Event [clear disable: MoDroid]
05-02 17:18:59.562: V/WifiMonitor(118): Event [Trying to associate with 00:26:82:73:2d:d3 (SSID='MoDroid' freq=2412 MHz)]
05-02 17:18:59.562: V/WifiMonitor(118): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=3 BSSID=00:26:82:73:2d:d3]
05-02 17:18:59.562: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=4 BSSID=00:26:82:73:2d:d3
05-02 17:18:59.572: V/WifiMonitor(118): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=4 BSSID=00:26:82:73:2d:d3]
05-02 17:18:59.572: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): Associated with 00:26:82:73:2d:d3
05-02 17:18:59.572: V/WifiMonitor(118): Event [Associated with 00:26:82:73:2d:d3]
05-02 17:18:59.572: V/WifiStateTracker(118): Changing supplicant state: SCANNING ==> ASSOCIATING
05-02 17:18:59.572: D/StatusBarPolicy(190): onSignalStrengthsChanged
05-02 17:18:59.582: D/StatusBarService(190): updateIcon slot=phone_signal index=20 viewIndex=13 old=StatusBarIcon(pkg=com.android.systemui id=0x7f0200d2 level=0 visible=true num=0 ) icon=StatusBarIcon(pkg=com.android.systemui id=0x7f0200d2 level=0 visible=true num=0 )
05-02 17:18:59.592: I/keystore(76): uid: 1000 action: t -> 3 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
05-02 17:18:59.592: V/WifiStateTracker(118): KeyStore.LOCKED
05-02 17:18:59.592: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): DISABLE_80211X
05-02 17:18:59.592: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): CTRL_IFACE: wpa_supplicant_ctrl_iface_disable_80211X
05-02 17:18:59.612: V/WifiStateTracker(118): Changing supplicant state: ASSOCIATING ==> ASSOCIATED
05-02 17:18:59.612: D/ConnectivityService(118): [embedded] ConnectivityChange for WIFI: CONNECTING/CONNECTING, default=-1
05-02 17:19:02.585: D/StatusBarPolicy(190): onSignalStrengthsChanged
05-02 17:19:02.585: D/StatusBarService(190): updateIcon slot=phone_signal index=20 viewIndex=13 old=StatusBarIcon(pkg=com.android.systemui id=0x7f0200d2 level=0 visible=true num=0 ) icon=StatusBarIcon(pkg=com.android.systemui id=0x7f0200d2 level=0 visible=true num=0 )
05-02 17:19:05.587: D/StatusBarPolicy(190): onSignalStrengthsChanged
05-02 17:19:05.587: D/StatusBarService(190): updateIcon slot=phone_signal index=20 viewIndex=13 old=StatusBarIcon(pkg=com.android.systemui id=0x7f0200d2 level=0 visible=true num=0 ) icon=StatusBarIcon(pkg=com.android.systemui id=0x7f0200d2 level=0 visible=true num=0 )
05-02 17:19:05.708: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): wpa_driver_wext_combo_scan: Start
05-02 17:19:06.078: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
05-02 17:19:06.078: V/WifiMonitor(118): Event [CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys]
05-02 17:19:06.078: V/WifiStateTracker(118): New network state is DISCONNECTED
05-02 17:19:06.088: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=0 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00
05-02 17:19:06.088: V/WifiMonitor(118): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=0 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00]
05-02 17:19:06.088: V/WifiStateTracker(118): Changing supplicant state: ASSOCIATED ==> DISCONNECTED
05-02 17:19:06.178: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=2 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00
05-02 17:19:06.178: V/WifiMonitor(118): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=2 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00]
05-02 17:19:06.178: V/WifiStateTracker(118): Changing supplicant state: DISCONNECTED ==> SCANNING
05-02 17:19:06.178: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): wpa_driver_wext_combo_scan: Start
05-02 17:19:06.188: W/wpa_supplicant(1323): ioctl[SIOCSIWPRIV] (cscan): -1
05-02 17:19:06.188: W/wpa_supplicant(1323): Failed to initiate AP scan.
05-02 17:19:07.229: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): got scan complete
05-02 17:19:07.229: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): wpa_supplicant_get_scan_results:return scan results2
05-02 17:19:07.229: W/wpa_supplicant(1323): ioctl[SIOCGIWSCAN]: 22
05-02 17:19:07.229: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): wpa_driver_wext_get_scan_results:buffer is NULL
05-02 17:19:07.229: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): wpa_drv_get_scan_results2:Failed to get scan results
05-02 17:19:07.229: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): Failed to get scan results - try scanning again
05-02 17:19:08.340: I/wpa_supplicant(1323): wpa_driver_wext_combo_scan: Start
```

http://pastebin.com/r23NQ2VC

Comment: I'm going to close this as "localized" since the issue stems from your specific Wi-Fi software rather than an Android issue, though feel free to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with the routing software [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/).

Comment: can you mark this as solved?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my t101 tablet. Sometimes, " forgetting" the network entry would work, but my final fix was this: I set my phone up as a hotspot and connected my tablet to that. After doing that twice my tf101 has connected to my router without fault. It's not a satisfying answer. Things shouldn't be so clunky, but here we are.